# Gradle build jars from multiple folders

Tags: gradle

I have a folder of unpacked jars like (As i removed the signatures):

```
folder
    - unpackedJar1
    - unpackedJar2
    - unpackedJar3
```

Now i want to repackage them again to jars like "unpackedJar1.jar", "unpackedJar2.jar" and so on with a custom manifest. How can I archive that? I can't find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Jar tasks with custom manifest dynamically for each folder and then assign them with an aggregate task. For example:

```groovy
task packAll{
    description = 'Pack all data in separated JARs'
}

//list of folders with unpacked data
def unpackedFolders = ['unpackedJar1', 'unpackedJar2', 'unpackedJar3']

//create new Jar task for each folder and make packAll depends on this one
unpackedFolders.each{ folderName ->
    def packTask = project.tasks.create(name: 'pack_' + folderName, type: Jar){
        archiveName = folderName + ".jar"
        from(project.files('folder/' + folderName))
        manifest{
            attributes( 
                'source': folderName
            )
        }
    }
    project.packAll.dependsOn packTask
}
```

Comment: Hey I haven't forgot this. Currently on vacation. I'll check once I'm back in the office. Looks promising